# RestKit: Data not mappable unless `pattern` is `nil`

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, restkit, restkit-0.20

I load data from the following URL:

```
https://myserver.com/api/kitchens/0af569e6-3e7d-4d6d-b8ca-7a70f93160c9/recipes/18488b51-04e0-4146-8ac6-05106db14024
```

The data looks like so:

```
{
  "recipe": {
    "id": "18488b51-04e0-4146-8ac6-05106db14024",
    "kitchen-id": "0af569e6-3e7d-4d6d-b8ca-7a70f93160c9",
    "rating": "",
    "title": "My recipe",
    "author": “John”,
    "date": "2014-05-10",
    "location": “Paris,
    "servings": 4,
    "customer-rating": 5.0,
    "ingredients": [

    ]
  }
}
```

I can map the data so my mapping is fine. However, as soon as I specify a pattern, I no longer get any data mapped. What is wrong with my pattern?

Here a comparison:

```
PATTERN
/api/kitchens/:kitchenID/recipes/:recipeID
URL PATH
/api/kitchens/0af569e6-3e7d-4d6d-b8ca-7a70f93160c9/recipes/18488b51-04e0-4146-8ac6-05106db14024
```

My Mapping code

```
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectStore:self.service.managedObjectStore];
NSDictionary *map = @{
                      @"id": @"id",
                      @"title": @"title",
                      @"rating": @"rating",
                      @"date": @"createdOn",
                      @"author": @"author",
                      @"servings": @"servings",
                      @"customer-rating": @"customerRating",
                      };
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:map];
result.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];


// This does not work
    NSString *pattern = @"/api/kitchens/:kitchenID/recipes/:recipeID"

// This works
NSString *pattern = nil;

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:pattern keyPath: @“recipe” statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

Comment: What is the base URL set to?

Comment: @wain: As you can see in the example. the base url is: `https://myserver.com/` do you think the `api/` bit should be part of the base url?

Comment: No, but I think you should remove the leading `/` from the start of all path patterns.

Comment: Negative, I tried to remove the slash and append it to the baseURL instead. This did not work.